# Problemas con DatePikerDialog al comparar fechas

Tags: android, datepicker

Estoy usando el DatePikerDialog para publicar noticias desde mi app android, este dialogo es lanzado por un boton en el que se eligue la fecha de publicación, la cual tiene que ser **mayor o igual que la fecha actual**, si esta es menor, salta un snackbar de información.

El caso es que cuando la fecha, es decir, el día coincide con el día actual algunas veces salta el snackbar (cosa que no tendía que pasar) y otras veces no, y no sé a que puede deberse esto. En el mismo código hago saltar un TimePickerDialog pero eso en principio no da problema. Adjunto el código en cuestión:

```
final Calendar fEle = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        final ArrayList total = new ArrayList();


        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener odsl = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                final Calendar hEle = Calendar.getInstance();
                hEle.set(Calendar.YEAR, i);
                hEle.set(Calendar.MONTH, i1);
                hEle.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i2);

                DateFormat formato=DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                total.add(formato.format(new Date(hEle.getTimeInMillis()))+" ");

                if (cal.before(fEle) || cal.equals(fEle)) {


                    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener otsl = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {

                            hEle.set(fEle.get(Calendar.YEAR), fEle.get(Calendar.MONTH), fEle.get(Calendar.DATE), i, i1);

                            if (cal.equals(fEle)) {

                                if (cal.getTime().after(hEle.getTime())) {
                                    Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.errFechaEmpiece, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .show();
                                } else {
                                    total.add(i + ":" + i1);
                                }

                            } else {
                                total.add(i + ":" + i1);
                            }

                            if(total.size()>=2) {
                                cambiarLaFechaDePublicacion((String) total.get(0), (String) total.get(1));
                            }

                        }
                    };

                    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), otsl,
                            java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().HOUR),
                            java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().MINUTE),
                            true);
                    dialog.show();


                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.errFechaEmpiece, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }


            }


        };

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), odsl,
                java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().YEAR),
                java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH),
                java.util.Calendar.getInstance().get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dpd.show();
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Puedes especificar cual condicion es la que se te esta saltando?

Comment: Si, es la primera condición donde comparo `if (cal.before(fEle) || cal.equals(fEle))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

le dejo el log con las diferentes pasadas.

```
  Log.v("Data cal ", cal.getTime().toString());
  Log.v("Data fEle ", fEle.getTime().toString());

        //Condicion original
        if (cal.before(fEle) || cal.equals(fEle)) {
```

**Priemra llamada** selecciono fecha 23/9/17, hora actual.

V/Data cal: Sat Sep 23 09:34:33 GMT-03:00 2017
V/Data fEle: Sat Sep 23 09:34:33 GMT-03:00 2017

**Salida:**
V/Data: cambiarLaFechaDePublicacion

**Segunda llamada** selecciono 21/9/17, dos días antes. Observe los valores de cal y fEle antes de pasar por el **if**

V/Data cal: Sat Sep 23 09:37:40 GMT-03:00 2017
V/Data fEle: Sat Sep 23 09:37:40 GMT-03:00 2017

**Salida:**
V/Data: cambiarLaFechaDePublicacion

**Tercera llamada** selecciono 25/9/17, dos dias posteriores a la fecha de hoy.

V/Data cal: Sat Sep 23 09:40:06 GMT-03:00 2017
V/Data fEle: Sat Sep 23 09:40:06 GMT-03:00 2017

**Salida:**
V/Data: cambiarLaFechaDePublicacion

Es decir que la condición siempre compara dos valores iguales.

Ahora las salidas con el código modificado como lo marque antes..

```
 Log.v("Data cal ", cal.getTime().toString());
 Log.v("Data hEle ", hEle.getTime().toString());

       //Condición modificada
        if (cal.before(hEle) || cal.equals(hEle)) {
```

**Primera llamada** selecciono fecha 23/9/17, hora actual. Note la diferencia de segundos.

V/Data cal: Sat Sep 23 09:44:13 GMT-03:00 2017
V/Data hEle: Sat Sep 23 09:44:18 GMT-03:00 2017

**Salida:**
V/Data: cambiarLaFechaDePublicacion

**Segunda llamada** selecciono 21/9/17, dos días antes. Sale por el Snackbar del DatePickerDialog pq la fecha es anterior.

V/Data cal: Sat Sep 23 09:45:55 GMT-03:00 2017
V/Data hEle: Thu Sep 21 09:45:58 GMT-03:00 2017

**Salida:**
V/Data: SnackBar2

**Tercera llamada** selecciono 25/9/17, dos dias posteriores a la fecha de hoy.
V/Data cal: Sat Sep 23 09:47:35 GMT-03:00 2017
V/Data hEle: Mon Sep 25 09:47:39 GMT-03:00 2017

**Salida:**
V/Data: cambiarLaFechaDePublicacion

La condición dentro del TimePickerDialog

```
    if (cal.equals(fEle)) {
```

Es también siempre verdadera por lo que se desprende de lo visto en la primer parte.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Observo esto en su código.

```
final Calendar fEle = Calendar.getInstance();
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

la primera condición siempre es verdadera.

```
if (cal.before(fEle) || cal.equals(fEle)) {
```

Los dos objetos calendar se crearon al mismo tiempo, es decir siempre debería ingresar al TimePickerDialog.

El error esta en no comparar **cal** contra **hEle** que seria la nueva fecha.

```
if (cal.before(hEle) || cal.equals(hEle)) {
   //Si la fecha seleccionada es igual o posterior
}else{
   //Si la fecha seleccionada es anterior
}
```

Otra opción que tienes para evitar dicho error es desactivar las fechas anteriores. Estableciendo la propiedad **setMinDate** del objeto DatePickerDialog, como se muestra en el ejemplo.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dd = null;
    try {
        dd = sdf.parse("21/9/2017");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,odsl,a,m,d);
    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(dd.getTime());
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Gustavo, agradezco tu respuesta, pero si miras un poco mas arriba de esa condición que dices que es verdadera, veras que seteo `hEle` a los valores que selecciona el usuario mediante la interfaz que se ejecuta cuando se llama al `DatePickerDialog`

Comment: Es verdad pero solo lo utilizas para el TimePickerDialog y no para el DatePickerDialog, me explico.

Comment: No, es al revés, si te fijas bien, la interfaz que se llama es la de DatePikerDialog primero, y es ahí donde seteo los valores y luego los meto en la condición

Comment: Perdón pero vuelvo a insistir que esta comparación no tiene sentido ya que los dos objetos se crearon al mismo tiempo.  if (cal.before(fEle) || cal.equals(fEle)) {. El valor que debe utilizar para la comparación es el del hEle. Realice la prueba por favor.

Comment: Amigo, creo que no entiendes como funciona esto, has probado el código al menos? Si es así vuelve a revisar mis respuestas

Comment: Si Adrian lo he probado, podes hacer un Log.v(cal.getTime().getString()); y Log.v(fEle.getTime().getString()); y podras comprobar que tranquilamente puedes eliminar la condicion